# How can I effectively deal with the dog, ninja, or addict?

Tags: superhot-mind-control-delete

The dog, ninja, and addict special enemies, like all enemies, appear to move a little bit faster than the player. Bullets bounce off of them (including shots with the piercing shot hack), and they can't be melee attacked (with the katana or regular punches). The berserk hack does not grant immunity to their attacks. The dog cannot be distracted by throwing a bone (yes, I tried).

Is there any reliable way to deal with them other than avoid them and try to finish the level before they kill you?